# Load HTML element with jQuery in DOM only if needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, mobile

**I want to load a sidebar on desktop and hide it on mobile, but not only hide it: delete it fully, so that it's not loaded**.

Before this, I tried using `media queries` and `remove` in jQuery, but in both of them, they are being loaded before they are hidden... So my solution now is to load a html only if I need them, but the problem is that I don't know how I have to do that.

Is this something like `$("#containerDiv").append();`?

I don't get it actually, because isn't this the same as removing it with jQuery or am I seeing it wrong? This ain't server side, right?

Comment: Two questions: 1) What's the problem with show/hide? 2) If there's a problem why not remove() it and then reappend it (listen to resize event)?

Comment: He dont wont to load it...

Comment: @reyaner load could mean load into the page DOM (which is understandable since it's a pretty expensive operation) or load the actual string html data.

Comment: I don't want to load it because it's resource intesive and I hate that if it's a mobile website. That's the problem with show and hide. And removing it would have it loaded, so that's not what I want as I said once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this not worked for you because you dont use 
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height" />`(i say you in your previous question icheck this with my android phone)
in all solution your page must load after that javascript change page
you have 3 way
1:use media queries
 
2:use previous way load page check page size and remove object
3:use server side
in php

```
function check_user_agent ( $type = NULL ) {
        $user_agent = strtolower ( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] );
        if ( $type == 'bot' ) {
                // matches popular bots
                if ( preg_match ( "/googlebot|adsbot|yahooseeker|yahoobot|msnbot|watchmouse|pingdom\.com|feedfetcher-google/", $user_agent ) ) {
                        return true;
                        // watchmouse|pingdom\.com are "uptime services"
                }
        } else if ( $type == 'browser' ) {
                // matches core browser types
                if ( preg_match ( "/mozilla\/|opera\//", $user_agent ) ) {
                        return true;
                }
        } else if ( $type == 'mobile' ) {
                // matches popular mobile devices that have small screens and/or touch inputs
                // mobile devices have regional trends; some of these will have varying popularity in Europe, Asia, and America
                // detailed demographics are unknown, and South America, the Pacific Islands, and Africa trends might not be represented, here
                if ( preg_match ( "/phone|iphone|itouch|ipod|symbian|android|htc_|htc-|palmos|blackberry|opera mini|iemobile|windows ce|nokia|fennec|hiptop|kindle|mot |mot-|webos\/|samsung|sonyericsson|^sie-|nintendo/", $user_agent ) ) {
                        // these are the most common
                        return true;
                } else if ( preg_match ( "/mobile|pda;|avantgo|eudoraweb|minimo|netfront|brew|teleca|lg;|lge |wap;| wap /", $user_agent ) ) {
                        // these are less common, and might not be worth checking
                        return true;
                }
        }
        return false;
}
```

this function check your agent call like below code

```
if(check_user_agent('mobile'))
{
   echo 'mobile content';
}
else if(check_user_agent('browser'))
{
   echo 'desktop content';
}
```

Comment: Thanks brother. What do you mean by server side? How?

Comment: what is you server side technology?? php? asp?

Comment: It's better to do this in chat, I guess. It's PHP btw.

Comment: no need @siyah , answer updated i use it for iranskygroup.com this code send mobile user to mobile.php file for me you can check link with mobile and tablet

Answer (score 1):

you can use below. Is it what you are looking.

```
if(// check if not mobile) {
    // load the html or jsp
    $( "#containerDiv" ).load( "ajax/test.html" );
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to load specific chunks of a html page? So not a whole new html page?

Comment: nope. That is not possible. Why donot you move that chunk in a different html and load that. If you are using it in other places you can include that html there also using above code